# Confused between Ad-hoc Enterprise Distribution and Enterprise Developer Program

Tags: ios, xcode

When using Xcode to distribute a build one of the options is "Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment", and if you choose this then later there is a checkbox called "Save for Enterprise Distribution".

This is described for example here: http://www.readwriteweb.com/mobile/2010/12/apple-best-kept-secret-how-to-do-ad-hoc-installs.php

However this and similar links does not mention anything about having to have a Developer Enterprise Program license to use this feature.

Which is why I'm confused - Do you need to have a Enterprise Developer Program license to use the "Save for Enterprise Distribution" feature to distribute test builds or can it be used with a regular developer license?

If you do need an Enterprise license why does this link and others not mention that? If you don't need a license why is it called "Enterprise Distribution" within Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is called "Enterprise Distribution" you do not need to be part of the iOS Enterprise Developer Program to distribute an Ad Hoc build in this way.

To make use of it just ensure you have an ad hoc distrubtion provisioning profile and the target devices have been added to the team devices list and associated with the profile.

Comment: Will the user be able to keep using the App, when the provisioning profile expired?